# input type = 'submit' styling doesn't appear in IE 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, styling

i trying to make styling my button on html, but in IE 7 it doesnt change anymore,

this is my css code :

```
input[type=submit]{
background:url('../images/btn_login.png')repeat-x; 
color:white;
font-size:15px;
border-radius:5px;
}
```

and this is my html code :

```
<input type='submit' value='Masuk'>
```

it would appear on other browser like firefox or chrome, but it like doesnt change on IE 7
perhaps i need add some specific css code for IE?

thanks

Comment: If you remove the repeat-x from background, does the rest of it work? I'm reading that IE7 didn't support background-repeat with `Different values for X & Y directions (two-value syntax)`, so maybe that's causing an issue.

Comment: You should clearly stop support for IE7, like seriously stop it. It's 2014 already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it by make it as a class
    .btn {
    background:url('../images/btn_login.png')repeat-x;
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
    border-radius:5px;
    }

and then call it you html code

```
<input type='submit' value='Masuk' class='btn'>
```